# Microsoft Azure Active Directory deployment errors

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, windows-server-2019

```json
{
  "code":"MarketplacePurchaseEligibilityFailed",
  "message":"Marketplace purchase eligibilty check returned errors. See inner errors for details. ",
  "details":[
    {
      "code":"BadRequest",
      "message":"Offer with PublisherId: 'cloud-infrastructure-services', OfferId: 'ad-dc-2019' cannot be purchased due to validation errors. For more information see details. Correlation Id: 'df53305a-8689-494a-95b3-a3ffaa517b2a' The offer with PublisherId: 'cloud-infrastructure-services', OfferId: 'ad-dc-2019' and PlanId: 'ad-dc-2019' cannot be used on selected subscription to purchase paid marketplace offers. Please choose another subscription or update this one to allow purchases. Learn more https://aka.ms/UpgradeFreeSub, https://aka.ms/Switch-Azure-Offer and https://aka.ms/Change-Credit-Card about updating subscriptions in Azure, Correlation Id: 'df53305a-8689-494a-95b3-a3ffaa517b2a'.[{\"The offer with PublisherId: 'cloud-infrastructure-services', OfferId: 'ad-dc-2019' and PlanId: 'ad-dc-2019' cannot be used on selected subscription to purchase paid marketplace offers. Please choose another subscription or update this one to allow purchases. Learn more https://aka.ms/UpgradeFreeSub, https://aka.ms/Switch-Azure-Offer and https://aka.ms/Change-Credit-Card about updating subscriptions in Azure, Correlation Id: 'df53305a-8689-494a-95b3-a3ffaa517b2a'.\":\"StoreApi\"}]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Good day world, am deploying Active Directory Domain Controller on Azure and its coming back with the error below. Has anyone met with this error?

hoping to hear from the greatest minds in here.

Thanks

Comment: It seems the error basically says it - you need a paid azure plan, your type of deployment is not supported for free plan? Basically Microsoft wants you to give them some money )

Comment: Hi Nikolay :) funny enough they have given me a credit of $200 as am trying to deploy this machine and getting this error. Does the credit ring any bell for you? or may be they need money from me as you had mentioned? :(

Comment: I am not an expert, just faced several times the situation that some purchases are not allowed for subscriptions with a limit (not bound to a real card). Your error looks similar to that. I'd try contacting Microsoft sales for exact answer.

Comment: much appreciated Nikolay. Let's see what they could come up with in response and advise. Much appreciated once more.

Comment: There is similar question to this check if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/230819/unable-to-deploy-centos-market-palce.html

Comment: Thank you so much -Mehtab Siddique. Now it rings the bell with the subscription issue. Much appreciated you all for responding with your suggestions. -Nikolay -Mehtab Siddique

Answer (score 0):

To add to Thomas's answer, the "MarketplacePurchaseEligibilityFailed" error is expected if you try to purchase a purchase a Market Place Item (in your case, [ad-dc-2019](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/cloud-infrastructure-services.ad-dc-2019?tab=overview) ) while using a free subscription. Certain services require a card on file even if you have enough credits to cover the costs. It doesn't necessarily mean that you'll get charged though.

To resolve this issue you need to [create a Pay-As-You-Go subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/purchase-options/pay-as-you-go/) with a credit card on file and try the steps again.